# Need to write a number of sequential http request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, axios

I have a back end automation process need to write 10 https request. The latter https request depends on the previous response. Basically I need to write the synchronous request. I used to program in PHP using guzzle for this. But the project require me to use nodejs.

In nodejs, I write the script using axios, but need to use 10 times for then() to chain the http request. The code looks very tedious. I used await, but I can get the response.

May I know if there is a better way for me to write the script?

My current nodejs is like. I will have 10 nested then().

The code is like this:

```
axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
code on the response
axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
    code on the response
    axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
        code on the response
        axios.get('url').then(function (response) {
        })
    })
})
})
```

Comment: "The code looks very tedious"  which code ?

Comment: the code is like:
axios.get('url').then(
 axios.get('url').then(
  axios.get('url').then(
   axios.get('url').then(
))))

Comment: Please use [edit] to edit your question, because code in a comment is not readable.

Comment: edited. basically need 10 nested then(). But it dont looks like a good way of writing for me.

Comment: is there any specific reason not to use `await`?

Comment: and any specific reason to nest those calls rather than chain them?

Comment: i am quite new to nodejs. But when I try to use await, there is a runtime error, say the await can only used in async function. My axios call is on main file.

Comment: may i know what does it meant by chain them ?

Comment: Why did you **not** show the code with the info on the runtime error ?

Comment: sorry, should be syntax erorr:
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Axios is capable of doing HTTP requests using `await`, see: https://www.memberstack.com/blog/node-http-request#:~:text=2.-,Axios%C2%A0,-According%20to%20Axios. you must be having an error in your code, which causes the syntax error.

Comment: Can you please add more details about when to run a next get?  Based on what conditions does it need to run? (a [mre] would be nice!)

Answer (score 0):

```
// needed if top-level await is not available
(async () => {
  const r1 = await axios.get('url')
  const r2 = await axios.get('url')
  // ...
})()
```

Comment: How it that going to help when: "The latter https request depends on the previous response." ?

Comment: They are running sequentially, `r2` will be executed when `r1` finishes

Comment: Super! this solve my questino on axios. But I have another question on mysql.